# What process is Streamreader using?

Tags: dispose, streamreader

I made a simple program with

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(dlg.FileName));                
txtBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

and forgot to put

```
sr.Dispose();
```

and now when I try to run the program and open a file I get the IOException was unhandled error message that says "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." So my question is, does anyone know what process is it using? I would like to be able to find it in the taskmanager and end it instead of writing a bunch of exception handling code since this is just a program that I'm using for practice.

The file I tried to open is a txt file in MyDocuments.

Comment: Sorry, only thing you can do in that case is hit your hard drive repeatedly with a sledgehammer. Then bury it in the backyard, lest other electronics in your house also become locked....but the process in question is most likely your own program; make sure that is terminated. Grab a tool called sysinternals processmonitor, it has functionality that will tell you what process is locking a resource.

Comment: Well, I just restarted my computer instead of taking the sledgehammer approach, and I don't want to do that next time, so I still want to know, out of all the processes that shut down on my computer when I shut it down, which was the one that I could've just ended?

Comment: And thanks for the info about sysinternals. I might get that.

Comment: did restarting your comp fixed the issue?

Comment: If you end a process that does not release file lock then there is not process to find.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with WPF, so i have removed the wpf tag.

Answer (score 2):

The process that is using the file is the process that opened it which is very likely .vshost.exe if you are running this from from Visual Studio.

To avoid 'forgetting' to dispose of objects in the future using the `using` statementfor anything implementing `IDisposable` (which `StreamReader` does). Your code would look like

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(dlg.FileName)))
{
    txtBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was using a streamreader to find out the end of the text in the file so I could then add the new text after the text in the file with the writeline method. My Documents has accessibility issues when it come to development anyway. Try putting the .txt into some other location maybe /temp folder?